# Using Kafka nodes in Bluemix and Node-Red

Tags: ibm-cloud, kafka-consumer-api, node-red, message-hub

I am trying to consume messages in a Bluemix node-red app using a Kafka input node (node-red-contrib-kafka-node).  I have a message-hub service bound to my app and I am writing messages to a topic using an on-prem java app.  What should go in the ZK Quorum property of the Kafka input node in order to be able to consume these messages?

Comment: Are you using an old version of the Kafka client?  You may need to pass credentials into Message Hub from Node.js,

Comment: @ValerieLampkin My package.json has node-red-contrib-kafka-node": "0.x"

Answer (score 2):

Since Message Hub is a secure Kafka installation and we don't provide allow public access to Zookeeper, the Kafka module just won't work with Message Hub. However, I just released a Node RED module that works with Message Hub using the official Message Hub Node.js client.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-messagehub-node

Please give it a try, be aware that this is the first version, I just created it as fast as possible so you can move on. If you have any further questions, please let me know.